# How can I start a Phoenix sub-app from the umbrella root directory

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a Phoenix umbrella app I can run
`mix phoenix.server` to compile and run all the apps. I would like to have a separate command to compile and run each sub-app independently.

The [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/up_and_running.html) say that it's possible but I've tried and failed to guess the format of the command.

> We can run mix phx.new from any directory in order to bootstrap our
>   Phoenix application. Phoenix will accept either an absolute or
>   relative path for the directory of our new project.

Comment: Just run `mix phx.server` from `apps/<your app>`? That should only start the specific application you're currently in.

Comment: Yes, I do know about that but the docs say there is a way to pass a relative path. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: That's for `mix phx.new` (to create a new app), not `phx.server`.

Answer (score 0):

From @Dogberts response this is a misunderstanding of the docs. Paths can be passed to create new apps with `phx.new` *not* to compile and run with `phx.server`